# Изменение букв на следующую в pascal

Tags: pascal

Как сделать так что-бы каждая буква в слове менялась на следующую? К примеру вводим абетка, выводит: бвёулб.

Answer (score 1):

Будет полезной функция Succ, которая, будучи применённой к значению перечислимого типа (а Char, из которых состоят строки, к ним относятся), возвращает следующее по порядку значение.

Comment: Так функция не поддерживает русский язык.

Comment: Ей наплевать на язык. Другое дело, что в таблице `ё` не по порядку - так что "е" и "я" придётся специальным образом обрабатывать (с "z" та же история )

Comment: Так по русски ошибку выдает.

Comment: Смотрите дано слово "аркуш", как преобразовать в бслфщ?

Comment: Какую ошибку? `s[i] := succ(s[i]);`

Comment: А буква i - это что?

Comment: Это индекс символа в строке. Функция применяется к каждому символу.